# How to know if the CPython executable is the debug version, in python?

Tags: python, cpython

We need to find out if our code is running under a CPython executable built with debugging enabled, programmatically. `sys` module did not seem to have any information, at least on `python3.4-dbg` of Ubuntu 14.04. `sys.flags.debug` is set to 0. The reason for this is that our code unmodified actually crashes the debug versions of python. **Update**: specifically the code crashes with an assertion error on the C side.

Surely there must be better than see if  `'d' in sys.executable`.

Comment: If your code crashes Python (debug or otherwise), you may want to consider raising a bug report on Python itself (if you haven't already done so, and assuming current Python *still* crashes). Short of doing badly-written C extensions, crashing Python itself with valid Python code should *not* be possible.

Comment: @paxdiablo [and this was done here](https://bugs.python.org/issue21385)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code might be what you're after

Using `python3.4`:

```
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_config_var('Py_DEBUG')
0
```

On the other hand using `python3.4-dbg`:

```
>>> import sysconfig
>>> sysconfig.get_config_var('Py_DEBUG')
1
```

However, there are also compile time options controlling "debug" behaviour, such as `NDEBUG` mentioned here: http://bugs.python.org/issue17411 .

In other words: though `Py_DEBUG` may be unset (0), the C-code asserts controlled by `NDEBUG` may still alter the behaviour of python. Setting `Py_DEBUG` always unsets `NDEBUG` resulting in asserts being applied. The lack of `Py_DEBUG` has no effect on `NDEBUG` - it may or may not be defined. If `NDEBUG` is defined, asserts will be defined as a void macro.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h :

> Programmers can eliminate the assertions just by recompiling the
>   program, without changing the source code: if the macro NDEBUG is
>   defined before the inclusion of , the assert() macro is
>   defined simply as:
>
> ```
> #define assert(ignore)((void) 0)
> ```

A possible, but unportable, solution would be to check compiler command line `OPT` for this:

```
>>> '-DNDEBUG' not in (sysconfig.get_config_var('OPT') or '')
```

where `OPT` could be for example

```
>>> sysconfig.get_config_var('OPT')
'-DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes'
```

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I hate C asserts - someone knew that things could go wrong but rather than handling it chose to test for it **in debug builds only** and things can just go to hell in the deliverable code - *(rant over, spleen vented)!*

Comment: Unportable yes, but at least this works on real operating systems, didn't know about Py_DEBUG and NDEBUG in sysconfig or their meanings, thanks.